# oracle sql query for number of occurrence of data between some values

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to number of occurrence of data between some values, lets take val as column  name having values from 1 2 3 4.... upto 100. I want count of 0 to 5 then count of 5 to 10 then count of 10 to 15 and soon upto 100.
Desired output is like

```
id  count(val)
1   35
2   12
3   89
4   45
5   12
```

I can do this by writing query like this.

```
select colname,
       sum(case 
             when val > 0 and val < 5 then 1 else 0 
           end) 
  from tablename 
 group by colname.
```

As range of column is wide I cannot write multiple case for this task.

Comment: "From 0 to 5, then from 5 to 10..." - Where should 5 be counted, in the first set or the second? (Or in both - counting it twice?) Then, in the query you write `val > 0 and val < 5` - so you don't want `0` and `5` counted here? You need to make up your mind. For example: from `0` (inclusive) to `5` (exclusive), or `val >=0 and val < 5`, then `val >= 5 and val < 10`, then ..... Do you want the results in rows or in columns? If in columns, there is no way to avoid having to write all the column names (and it's a poor practice in general, anyway). Also: are there lower and upper bounds for `val`?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a histogram. One way to achieve your desired result is with the `width_bucket()` function:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions214.htm

You may need to generate rows for the intervals with a count of 0 - you could do that, for example, with an outer join to a table (which you can generate easily on the fly) having all the values of `b` from `1` to `20` (using my notation below).

```
with
     test_data ( id, val ) as (
       select 1, 35 from dual union all
       select 2, 12 from dual union all
       select 3, 89 from dual union all
       select 4, 45 from dual union all
       select 5, 12 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select   5 * (b - 1) as int_from, 5 * b as int_to, count(1) as ct
from     ( select width_bucket(val, 0, 100, 20) as b from test_data )
group by b
order by b
;

  INT_FROM     INT_TO         CT
---------- ---------- ----------
        10         15          2
        35         40          1
        45         50          1
        85         90          1

4 rows selected.
```